# count quantity of each registration type is not working properly

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get the quantity of each registration type with the code below:

```
$registrationTypeDetails = Registration::with('participants:id,registration_type_id,registration_id')->find($regID);

$type_counts = [];
foreach ($registrationTypeDetails->participants as $p) {
    $name = $p->registration_type->name;
    if (!isset($type_counts[$name])) {
        $type_counts[$name] = 0;
    }
    $type_counts[$name]++;
}
```

The dd($type_counts) if the user is doing a registraton with 2 registration types "general" and one registration type "plus" shows:

```
array:2 [▼
  "geral" => 2
  "plus" => 1
]
```

So it's working fine. But then I need to make a post request to an API where is necessary to send in the request body the quantity of each registration type, in this case for the registration type "general" the value should be "2" and for the registration type "plus" the value should be "1".

But it's not working properly, the value is always "1" for both registration types.

Do you know where is the issue?

```
foreach($registration->conference->registrationTypes as $key=>$registrationType){
    $items['invoice']['items'][]  = [
        'name' => $registration->conference->registrationTypes[$key]['name'],
        'unit_price' => $registration->conference->registrationTypes[$key]['price'],
        'quantity' => $type_counts[$name],
    ];
}

$create = $client->request('POST', 'https://...', [
    'query' => ['api_key' => '...'], 'json' => $items,
]);
```

The result array has the quantity "1" like below but the quantity should be "2" for registration type "general" and "1" for "plus":

```
array:1 [▼
  "invoice" => array:4 [▼
    "client" => array:7 [▶]
    "items" => array:2 [▼
      0 => array:5 [▼
        "name" => "general"
        "unit_price" => 10
        "quantity" => 1
      ]
      1 => array:5 [▼
        "name" => "plus"
        "unit_price" => 0
        "quantity" => 1
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: `participants:id` is that a typo in the `with` method? With is for eager loading relations, not selecting table columns.

Comment: Thanks it shoudl be necessary for the relation no? The "dd($registrationTypeDetails);" shows "Registration {#335 ▼
  #fillable: array:3 [▶]
 ...
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "participants" => Collection {#333 ▼
      #items: array:3 [▼
        0 => Participant {#342 ▶}
        1 => Participant {#343 ▶}
        2 => Participant {#344 ▶}
      ]
    }
  ]
...
}".

Comment: No, all you need is `Registration::with('participants')->get()`

Comment: Thanks, but same issue changing from "$registrationTypeDetails = Registration::with('participants:id,registration_type_id,registration_id')->find($regID);" to "        $registrationTypeDetails = Registration::with('participants')->find($regID);
".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$name` is never changed in the registration types loop:

```
// the $name index is always the same
'quantity' => $type_counts[$name],
```

Comment: Thanks, so maybe like this is correct "'quantity' => $type_counts[$registration->conference->registrationTypes[$key]['name']]"?